# HtmlUnit: TypeError: Cannot read property "mousedown" from null

Tags: java, htmlunit

ubable to click on input button in htmlunit using JAVA, when I try following code it gives me exception "TypeError: Cannot read property "mousedown" from null"

```
    HtmlSubmitInput search_button = (HtmlSubmitInput) page.getByXPath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PortalPageControl1_ctl08_PSCDocumentSearchControl1_searchButton']").get(0);
        HtmlPage results_page = search_button.click();
```

I have also tries to cast button into **HtmlButton** and **HtmlElement**

can any one tell me that what would be best cast for input type "submit"

Comment: How try with xpath `"//input[@id='<yourid>']"` ???

Answer (score 0):

well i've used htmlunit in both ways to parse a page. The xpath way is a bit more secure to request an element but you have to know the exact name. The findbyid or findbyname its easier but if the certain website uses a framework then the id's and name's of html elements wont be the same , however xpath will be. 
so i would suggest to try first get the button by id or by name to see that its working.

```
  HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("searchButton");
  HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out solution, but I don't know how it works exactly, when I add some delay before clicking on button, it works fine, may be due to some JS loading.

```
    HtmlSubmitInput search_button = (HtmlSubmitInput) page.getByXPath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PortalPageControl1_ctl08_PSCDocumentSearchControl1_searchButton']").get(0);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    HtmlPage results_page = search_button.click();
```